# What was the most common wand wood?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Out of all of the wands we know of in the Harry Potter universe, which wood was mentioned the most, or from our limited knowledge appears to be most common?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Annoyingly, the [Pottermore page on Wand woods](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods) lists an abundance of "uncommon" woods, but no indication of which are "common." However, based on our limited sample size, the answer appears to be either **chestnut**, **cherry**, **aspen**, or **mayhaw**, depending on how accurate you want to be.

### The Case for Chestnut

Chestnut wins handily if you're counting by confirmed owners; canon tells us there have been five:

- **Wormtail:**

  > "So I should use this one?" said Ron, pulling Wormtail's wand out of his pocket and handing it to Ollivander.
  >
  > "Chestnut and dragon heartstring. Nine-and-a-quarter inches. Brittle. I was forced to make this shortly after my kidnapping, for Peter Pettigrew. Yes, if you won it, it is more likely to do your bidding, and do it well, than another wand."
  >
  > <sup><sub>*Deathly Hallows* Chapter 24: "The Wandmaker"</sub></sup>
- **Professor Kettleburn.** This was formerly on Pottermore, and was confirmed in [*Pottermore Presents: Short Stories from Hogwarts of Heroism, Hardship, and Dangerous Hobbies*](https://www.pottermore.com/news/pottermore-presents-ebook-series-published-september).
- **[Three unnamed heads of the Wizengamot](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods):**

  > Conversely, three successive heads of the Wizengamot have possessed chestnut and unicorn wands, for this combination shows a predilection for those concerned with all manner of justice.

### The Case for Cherry

Cherry wins the day if you allow for a little educated guesswork, which we'll get to in a moment.

There are three confirmed owners of a cherry wand:

- **Neville** gets a cherry wand after breaking his first one at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*:

  > I thought Gran would be angry about all the publicity," said Neville, "but she was really pleased. Says I'm starting to live up to my dad at long last. She bought me a new wand, look!"
  >
  > He pulled it out and showed it to Harry.
  >
  > "Cherry and unicorn hair," he said proudly.
  >
  > <sup><sub>*Half-Blood Prince* Chapter 7: "The Slug Club"</sub></sup>
- **[Lockhart](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/gilderoy-lockhart):**

  > **Wand** Cherry and dragon heartstring, nine inches, slightly bendy
- **Mary Cattermole:**

  > "A wand was taken from you upon your arrival at the Ministry today, Mrs. Cattermole," Umbridge was saying. "Eight-and-three-quarter inches, cherry, unicorn-hair core. Do you recognize the description?"
  >
  > <sup><sub>*Deathly Hallows* Chapter 13: "The Muggle-Born Registration Commission"</sub></sup>

Additionally, according to [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods), cherry wands are highly-regarded in Japan:

> This very rare wand wood creates a wand of strange power, most highly prized by the wizarding students of the school of Mahoutokoro in Japan, where those who own cherry wands have special prestige.

This is where the guesswork comes in; it seems reasonable to believe that more than two people in Japan had a cherry wand, but we have no way of directly confirming this.

### The Case For Aspen

Aspen *maybe* wins, if you allow for a lot more fudging of numbers; we have absolutely no idea how many people had them. However, according to [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods), there were enough to have their own club:

> An infamous and secretive eighteenth-century duelling club, which called itself The Silver Spears, was reputed to admit only those who owned aspen wands.

So there were *probably* more than five, but once again we don't know for sure.

### The Case for [Mayhaw](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/1920s-wizarding-america-en)

Mayhaw was the wood of choice (the *only* wood of choice) for American wandmaker Violetta Beauvais:

> Violetta Beauvais, the famous wandmaker of New Orleans, refused for many years to divulge the secret core of her wands, which were always made of swamp mayhaw wood.
>
> <sup>[*Pottermore* 1920s Wizarding America](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/1920s-wizarding-america-en)</sup>

Although there's only one Beauvais wandholder identified (MACUSA President Seraphina Picquery), there were clearly many, many others; the American wandmaking industry was dominated by four individuals, so statistically we'd expect 25% of American wizards in the 1920s to have a Beauvais (and therefore a mayhaw) wand.

### Other woods

Just for the sake of completeness<sup>1</sup>:

- **Ash** 2
- **Blackthorn** 2
- **Hornbeam** 2
- **Poplar** 2
- **Willow** 2
- **Alder** 1
- **Apple** 1
- **Beech** 1
- **Birch** 1
- **Cypress** 1
- **Ebony** 1
- **Elder** 1
- **Elm** 1
- **Fir** 1
- **Hawthorn** 1
- **Hazel** 1
- **Larch** 1
- **Mahogany** 1
- **Maple** 1
- **Oak** 1
- **Rosewood** 1
- **Vine** 1
- **Walnut** 1
- **Yew** 1

---

<sup>1</sup> In the interests of brevity I haven't sourced any of the items on this list. I do, however, *have* sources, and will provide them if anyone asks, provided they've observed the proper rituals<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup> Nothing too fancy; sacrificing a copy of *Harry Potter and the **Sorcerer's** Stone* by the light of a full moon. That sort of thing.

Comment: Walnut and rowan seem like good candidates for woods indirectly named as common; at least, their descriptions seem to imply commonness.

Comment: Does that list include the wands Harry tried out an Ollivanders, before he found his match?

Comment: @CreationEdge It does! Beech and dragon heartstring; ebony and unicorn hair; and maple and phoenix feather

Comment: The wizard in Olivander's shop (at Univeral Orlando) said "a wand of weir" or something during the wand choosing. Know anything about it?

Comment: @RedCaio I do not; I don't know of any species of tree that fits the name (aside from the [fictional one from *ASOIAF*](https://m.westeros.org/index.php/Weirwood)), and the [Universal Orlando store](https://www.universalorlando.com/Merchandise/Shop/Harry_Potter/Collectibles.html) contains nothing illuminating. Unless you misheard, I can offer no explanation

Comment: But... but *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* **is** the name of the book :P

Comment: @DBPriGuy You are dead to me.

Comment: Cherry is actually not common. The Pottermore's description of Chery "This very rare wand wood creates a wand of strange power, most highly prized by the wizarding students of the school of Mahoutokoro in Japan, where those who own cherry wands have special prestige. "  https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods

Comment: @Randomperson You're not wrong, which really just hints at the inherent flaw in my methodology; not my best work, here

Answer (score 1):

### Beech and Cedar

According to *Ollivanders Bespoke Wand Selector*, one's wand wood is determined by your eye colour, the trait you're most proud of and the path you choose.

Out of the 189 possible permutations (9*7*3) of these factors, the following nine all lead to Beech and Cedar

> **Beech**
>
> 1. Dark brown/Black, Determination, Sea
> 2. Brown, Originality, Castle
> 3. Hazel, Optimism, Castle
> 4. Blue, Determination, Castle
> 5. Blue/Grey, Originality, Forest
> 6. Blue/Green, Kindness, Forest
> 7. Green, Originality, Sea
> 8. Green, Optimism, Forest
> 9. Grey, Imagination, Forest
>
> **Cedar**
>
> 1. Dark brown/Black, Originality, Forest
> 2. Brown, Imagination, Forest
> 3. Hazel, Determination, Sea
> 4. Blue, Determination, Forest
> 5. Blue/Grey, Determination, Castle
> 6. Blue/Green, Optimism, Forest
> 7. Green, Optimism, Castle
> 8. Grey, Imagination, Castle
> 9. Other, Originality, Castle
>
> <sub>(Information about Pottermore's wand quiz is taken from [Kira's Wand Spreadshhet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAZ59lsiqap1pQAAjr1ncy589LLHtHfoxyfFCrYqPGY/).)</sub>

This gives Beech and Maple each a 4.8% distribution of the the wands (significantly higher than the 2.6% average). The next most common wand is Maple.

---

Comment: You seem to be assuming that all eye colours, traits and paths are equally common. That doesn't appear to be true for eye colour at least.

Comment: @Blackwood - That is a fair point, but there is some evidence that Rowling designed the quiz assuming everything was equal. (Which is why Phoenix ends up being the most commonly gotten core, despite being intended to be the rarest.)